# On consecutive runs `terraform apply` tries to update the hostname after it was set properly

Tags: terraform, openstack

I'm setting my hostname using a cloud-init file which has this,

```
hostname: "${hostname}"
fqdn: "${fqdn}"
```

This sets the hostname and fqdn to the results of the DHCP setting on a port,

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = templatefile(
    "cloud/cloud.cfg",
    {
      hostname = openstack_networking_port_v2.port_company.dns_assignment[0].hostname
      fqdn     = openstack_networking_port_v2.port_company.dns_assignment[0].fqdn
    }
  )
}
```

The problem here is that while this works the first time, the second time it ends up doing this,

```
Changes to Outputs:
  ~ fqdn         = "host-10-2-68-89.openstack.build." -> "test-server.openstack.build."
  ~ hostname     = "host-10-2-68-89" -> "test-server"
  ~ instance_ips = "192.168.199.45" -> (known after apply)
```

How can I properly set my hostname with cloud-init using Terraform?